# storing 3 input values in single cookie and using it in subpage

Tags: javascript, html

storing multiple inputs in single cookie 

  My Cart

20000 usd

```
            <p>30000 usd</p>

<form name="woman1">
    <input type="number" min="0" style="width:80px;" name="woman2"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Add To Cart" onclick="add_to_cart()"/>
</form>
```

10000 usd

```
<form name="baby1" >
    <input type="number" min="0" style="width:80px;" name="baby2"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Add To Cart" onclick="add_to_cart();"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Show us your `add_to_cart()` code

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to store info in a cookie, use Javascript or PHP.

In Javascript, you make a cookie by doing this:

```
 document.cookie = "var_name=value; expires=Tells when the cookie should expire";
```

In PHP it would be:

```
 setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, when_to_expire);
```

Note: the expire is optional.
Also, the setcookie function needs to be placed before any HTML.